# Images are not showing in <el-carousel></el-carousel> of Element-ui

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to put some images in  Element-ui of Vue Framework but the images don't appear on the page.. I'm really new in Vue Framework. Anyone please help me to solve it.

```
<template>
<div>
  <el-carousel indicator-position="outside">
    <el-carousel-item v-for="item in img" :key="item">
      <img :src="item" />
    </el-carousel-item>
  </el-carousel>
</div>
```

```
export default {
name: "Home",
data() {
  return {
    img: [
      require("@/assets/homepage.png"),
      require("@/assets/honor.jpg"),
      require("@/assets/homepage.png"),
      require("@/assets/huaweip30.jpg"),
    ],
  };
},
```

Thanks

Comment: I have updated the above code and now it works properly. :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
    return {
      carouselImages: [
        'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png',
        'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png',
      ],
    };
  },
  };
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.2/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.2/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
<el-carousel :interval="6000" height="200px">
  <el-carousel-item v-for="item in carouselImages" :key="item">
    <img :src="item" class="image">
   </el-carousel-item>
</el-carousel>
</template>
</div>
```